# Wiring multiple baseboard heaters each with it own stat with one 10-2wg line

Tags: electrical, wiring, baseboard

Wiring multiple baseboard heaters each with it own stat with one 10-2wg line and 20amp dbl pole.

I wired these new heater up using double pole stats. the 10-2 runs close to each heater to a junction box.
all like colors junction and one line splits off to feeds w,b,g to heater, other line feeds w,b,g on to next stat and heater and etc to last heater.

Heater #1 works fine heater 2 and 3 have 120 on each white and black  but heater 2 and 3 do not work.

Whats could be the problem?  heaters total up to to less than 3500 watts.

Thanks in advance for help

Comment: Where are the thermostats wired into this setup at? Are they integral with the baseboard heaters, or separate?

Comment: If these are 240V heaters, remember to re-mark all white wires with black tape, or preferably, red tape.

Comment: Description appears to put the themostat before the junction. The junctions should be before the thermostat - so the "line splits off" should be going off from the junction of unswitched wires, to a thermostat, to a heater.

Comment: The stats are mounted on the right side  of the baseboard heaters

Comment: Junction boxes are before stat and heater

Comment: Have you measured white to black to verify there is 240v I know you said each has 120v  .